# cost OpenAI usage in RAG retrievel augmented generation Pipeline (LangChain, FAISS, OpenAI)

Tags: token, openai-api, langchain, faiss, retrieval-augmented-generation

I am not sure how to estimate the complete cost of OpenAI usage in the RAG pipeline I am building. I want to track beforehand the token usage and the associated cost. Here are some code snippets:

`model_name = 'text-embedding-ada-002'`

`embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(`
`model=model_name,`
`openai_api_key=openai_api_key`
`)`

```
def create_and_load_faiss_index(chunks, embeddings, index_path):
    try:
        # Create a FAISS index from documents
        db = FAISS.from_documents(chunks, embeddings)

        # Save the FAISS index locally
        db.save_local(index_path)

        # Load the FAISS index from the saved location
        db = FAISS.load_local(index_path, embeddings)

        return db

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return None
```

`db = create_and_load_faiss_index(chunks, embeddings, index_path)`

`retriever = db.as_retriever()`

`template = """…"""`

`prompt_template = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=template)`
`print(prompt_template)`

`llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4", temperature=0)`

`rag_chain = (`
`{"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}`
`| prompt_template`
`| llm`
`| StrOutputParser()`
`)`

`query = f"…"`

`openai_output = rag_chain.invoke(query)`

## Track OpenAI usage (embeddings AND RAG): To track the usage beforehand, I need to calculate the cost of calling "text-embedding-ada-002" in the embeddings phase and "gpt-4" in the rag phase. For calling gpt-4 in RAG, I came across "get_openai_callback()". What about the embedding phase? Thinking about that gpt-4 will retrieve its information from the faiss index, this does not include any tokens in that sense, correct?

```
with get_openai_callback() as cb:
    openai_output = rag_chain.invoke(query)
    print(cb)
```

## Which returns something like:

`Tokens Used: 37`
`Prompt Tokens: 4`
`Completion Tokens: 33`
`Successful Requests: 1`
`Total Cost (USD): $7.2e-05`

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the result was not same.
I couldn't reduce Prompt Tokens(On the contrary, little bit increased prompt tokens and responsetime).
but embedded prompt returned better answer.

### Case1

**Non embedded prompt**

```
"prompt_tokens": 3295,
"completion_tokens": 347,
"openai_process_time": 4.253575,
```

**Embedded prompt**
(answered better)

```
"prompt_tokens": 3602,
"completion_tokens": 686,
"openai_process_time": 8.553565,
```

### Case2

**Non embedded prompt**

```
"prompt_tokens": 3355,
"completion_tokens": 347,
"openai_process_time": 4.67733,
```

**Embedded prompt**
(answered better)

```
"prompt_tokens": 3669,
"completion_tokens": 583,
"openai_process_time": 7.52354,
```

---

those were resulted with GPT-3.5.
but also GPT-4 didn't reduce prompt tokens.